# convert a double to int using union?

Tags: c, unions

Suppose I have a union defined as:

```
typedef union{
    double d;
    int i;
} dtoi;
```

If I want to convert a double to an int, and I have the following function:

```
int doubleToInt(double d){
    dtoi dToI;
    dToI.d = d;
    return dToI.i;
}
```

And later I have another function to convert it back to double:

```
double intToDouble(dtoi dToI){
    return dToI.d;
}
```

Would this work? Right now I think I'm getting a wrong value of double. I think I don't quite understand how union and passing union as parameters across functions and modules work.

Comment: have you tried return (int)dToI.d ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This will not work. For one thing, `int` is usually 32 bits and `double` is usually 64. For another, floating-point values are basically split into bit fields, with so many bits holding the mantissa, so many holding the exponent, and one holding the sign. And integer, on the other hand is simply a base-2 representation of a number. Their bits just aren't arranged the same.

To correctly convert a double 'd' to an int, try `int i = (int)d;` and the reverse: `double d = (double)i;`. These actually convert the values from one format to another. A union just reinterprets the existing bits.

Answer (score 3):

> Would this work?

No, this won't work.

When you use a `union`, it is undefined behavior to set one member and extract a different member.

When you set the `int` member, you should extract only the `int` member.

You can implement `doubleToInt` without using a `union`.

```
int doubleToInt(double d){
    return (int)d;
}
```

You don't need a function to convert an `int` to a `double`. The compiler will do that for you automatically. If you must have a function, it is trivial.

```
double intToDouble(int in) {
   return in;
}
```

Comment: but when I convert it back to double, I would lose the numbers after the decimal point

Comment: @ballballbobo, As the doctor says, "if it hurts when you do that, then don't do that." Just keep the `double`, and cast to `int` when you need only the integer part.